# Need help in assembly for dosbox

Tags: assembly

So im having some difficulty doing what should be a really easy task in dosbox-printing a binary number. I've tried a lot of different things but cant get it to work right. This is my code for right now. Im using a windows system dosbox, v2022.12.26. I genuinely cannot figure this out. Any help will be appreciated.

This code should print right but instead prints infinite empty spaces.

```
org 100h
number db 0AFh      ; 8-bit number to display in binary
string db 'HELLO WORLD$', 0  ; String to convert and display
binForm db '00000000$', 0    ; Placeholder for binary form

start:

    ; Convert number to binary form
    mov cx, 8          ; 8 bits to process
    mov al, number
    mov di, binForm    ; Store the address of binForm directly

convert_to_binary:
    rol al, 1          ; Rotate left to get each bit to carry flag
    mov bl, [di]       ; Load the byte at the current position in binForm
    mov bh, 0          ; Clear BH to store the result (either '0' or '1')
    adc bh, 0          ; Add carry flag to '0', results in '0' or '1'
    mov [di], bh       ; Store the result back at the current position in binForm
    inc di             ; Move to the next byte in binForm
    loop convert_to_binary

    ; Print binary form
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, binForm    ; Load the address of binForm directly
    int 21h

    ; New line
    mov dl, 13
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    mov dl, 10
    int 21h

    ; Convert and print string
    mov si, string

print_string:
    lodsb             ; Load string byte into AL
    or al, 20h        ; Convert uppercase to lowercase
    cmp al, 0         ; Check for null-terminator
    je done           ; Jump to end if null-terminator
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h           ; Print character
    jmp print_string  ; Loop for next character

done:
    mov ax, 4C00h     ; Exit to DOS
    int 21h
```

Comment: `adc bh, 0` should be `adc bh, '0'` or `adc bh, 30h`. As the comment says, you need to convert to ascii. PS: the `mov bl, [di]` is useless.

Comment: You may have to move the data (`number`, `string`, and `binform`) to **after** your code not to be executed, depending of the format of your executable file.

Comment: `print_string` is infinity loop because of `or al, 20h` and `mov ah, 02h / mov dl, al / int 21h` prints char on the screen.

Comment: `or al, 20h / cmp al, 24h` should help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Using single step and watch to see if each instruction does what you think it should?  If so, the indicate which instruction isn't working or where you think it is going wrong.  If not, then now is a great time to enhance your debugging skills.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
    mov bl, [di]       ; Load the byte at the current position in binForm
    mov bh, 0          ; Clear BH to store the result (either '0' or '1')
    adc bh, 0          ; Add carry flag to '0', results in '0' or '1'
    mov [di], bh       ; Store the result back at the current position in binForm
```

You are not using the value loaded to `bl` and storing values `0x00` or `0x01` to the memory.

If you want to store ASCII **characters** `'0'` or `'1'` (values `0x30` or `0x31`), you have to add the offset `0x30` to your value.

```
    mov bh, 0          ; Clear BH to store the result (either '0' or '1')
    adc bh, 0x30       ; Add carry flag to '0', results in '0' or '1'
    mov [di], bh       ; Store the result back at the current position in binForm
```

Or if you want to use `bl`:

```
    mov bl, [di]       ; Load the byte at the current position in binForm
    adc bl, 0          ; Add carry flag to '0', results in '0' or '1'
    mov [di], bl       ; Store the result back at the current position in binForm
```

Or simpler way (using what initially is in the memory, but not using `bl`):

```
    adc byte [di], 0   ; Store the result back at the current position in binForm
```